# How to change font size in Euler plot in R?

Tags: r, plot, eulerr

I am trying to create a Euler diagram in R using the `eulerr` package. I would like to reduce the font size of the quantities text on the plot.

I have tried using `cex=0.5` (as per example below) and have also tried `fontsize =` and `font =` but none have reduced the font size. Am I placing `cex=0.5` in the wrong position?

```
    library(eulerr)

    set1 <- euler(c("A&B" = 3103,
            "A&C" = 1034,
            "A&D" = 118,
            "B&C" = 2690,
            "B&D" = 1017,
            "C&D" = 1383,
            "A&B&C" = 394,
            "A&B&D" = 73,
            "A&C&D" = 45,
            "B&C&D" = 153,
            "A&B&C&D" = 32))

    eulerr.plot <- plot(set1,
                fills = list(fill = c("#009292", "#FFB6DB", "#B66DFF", "#6DB6FF"), alpha = 0.7),
                labels = NULL, quantities = TRUE, legend = list(labels = c("A", "B", "C", "D")), cex = 0.5)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can change the text size of the quantities by passing a list defining the size to that argument like so:

```
plot(set1,  fills = list(fill = c("#009292", "#FFB6DB", "#B66DFF", "#6DB6FF"), alpha = 0.7),
                    labels = NULL, quantities = list(cex = .5), legend = list(labels = c("A", "B", "C", "D")))
```

[image]